# float divs overlapping

Tags: html, overlapping

I'm trying to make this testing site for a friend. It has 4 fixed position divs with one div in the middle that will scroll. Problem is the bodyline div is overlapping the left div.

http://jsfiddle.net/H23du/

there is a preview of what is wrong.

Can anyone help, I can explain anything else more if needed. though the JSfiddle shows the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed DIVs are no longer part of the DOM flow, and cannot be used as a point of reference for you center div. However, you may use their percentage or pixel-based widths as a way to determine margin for the center DIV.

Ergo, a left side div with a width of 30px would mean the center div would need a left margin of 30px;

It really just comes down to math from here.

Now, if you floated the divs with relative positioning, rather than fixing them, it would be a different story.

Comment: yeah these need to be fixed. for they are not to move what so ever.

Comment: @ChristopherButcherBaldwin yeah, so set your margins equal to the width of your fixed Divs, and the width of the center div equal to the wrapper minus the total width of both divs

Answer (score 0):

Try: `width:25%;` and `padding: 0px 0px 0px 60px;` and `text-align: justify;` in `#bodyline`.